# Multiple custom checkboxes in Vue3 react differently when clikcing label vs input

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, vuejs3

I have a custom checkbox where the input and a separate (custom) label flip the `checked` value. When `checked` is changed, a watch picks it up and $emits the value to the parent.

In the parent, I have two of the same Toggle components, however when I click the Toggle input, it only triggers the first toggle (unexpected). If I click the label, it triggers the correct toggle switch (as expected).

Can someone please explain what is happening here?

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-base-forked-3ppj0j?file=/src/components/Toggle.vue

The event being emitted is the same, regardless of clicking the label or the input, so why does one work and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have same id for both checkboxes. Id has to be unique so it actually is only applied to first element.
As `<label>` is linked to checkbox via `id` - both labels are linked to 1st element.

Simplest solution is passing `id` value as a property:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-base-forked-1mgcj3?file=/src/components/Page.vue

Another way would be to generate unique id with something like **Vue UUID** package.
This way you don't need to pass anything from parent component

Comment: Sometimes the easiest stuff trips us up. In this case, I seemed to have forgotten how checkboxes work altogether! This was the solution to the problem and also brought peace to my overworked brain. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In Toggle.vue, I change something and here is my answer.

```html
<label class="switch" :for="label">
  <input :id="label" v-model="checked" type="checkbox" />
  <div class="slider round" />
</label>
```